# JavaFX CSS ChoiceBox and ComboBox

Tags: javafx

I want to make a dark mode but i cant find any information on how to change the color of the checkmark (its currently black on black), can anyone help me?

I have tried:

```
.choiceBox .context-menu {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-border-color: #ffffff;
}

.choiceBox .menu-item:focused {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-background-color: #222222;
}

.choiceBox .menu-item > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}

.choiceBox .menu-item:focused > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}

.choiceBox > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Sort of off-topic, but it looks like you are doing way too much work here to "theme" your application. Almost all colors in the default stylesheet are defined as "looked-up colors", and are derived from the color `-fx-base`. So a CSS stylesheet containing just `.root { -fx-base: #101010;}`, for example, will create a dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "arrow".  This changes it to yellow:

```
.choice-box > .open-button > .arrow,
.combo-box-base > .arrow-button > .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: yellow, yellow;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.333333em 0.166667em 0.333333em; /* 2 4 2 4 */
    -fx-shape: "M 0 0 h 7 l -3.5 4 z";
}
```

Comment: Or (simpler) `.root { -fx-mark-color: yellow; -fx-mark-highlight-color: yellow;}`.